# Facebook button won't show up

Tags: javascript, php, html

So i'm trying to make a log-in page for a hotspot, where the user logs in with facebook and is then redirected to the router to get access to the internet, but no matter what i try the facebook login button just won't appear. Here's a simple code trying to make appear the button but it just won't work

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>facebook login </title>
  </head>
  <body>

<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '1749574641802184',
      cookie     : false,
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v3.0'
    });

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
     statusChangeCallback(response);
}); 

  };

 (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.0&appId=2034911913423175&autoLogAppEvents=1';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));;

  function statusChangeCallback(response){
    if(response.status === "conected"){
      setElements(true);
      console.log("logged in and authenticated");
    }
  }


function checkLoginState() {
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
    window.top.location = "";
  });
}

</script>


<fb:login-button 
  scope="public_profile,email"
  onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>

<div class="fb-login-button" data-width="300" data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" data-button-type="continue_with" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="false"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: Two different `appId` values don’t make you go, “hm, can this be right?” on your own …?

Comment: Are you receiving any console errors? Also please check the network requests to fetch the JavaScript from Facebook are successful.